# Матрица кратчайших путей Флойд

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Пытаюсь написать прогу для нахождения кратчайших маршрутов между вершинами графа. Размер кратчайших маршрутов между двумя вершинами находит нормально, а матрицу самих маршрутов создать не получается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int n = 10;

vector<vector<int>> vec(n);
vector<vector<int>> path(n);

void Path(int u, int v)
{
    if (vec[u][v] == 99)
        cout << "No path found";              
    else
    {
        int c = u;
        while (c != v)
        {
            cout << c << " ";
            c = path[c][v];
        }
        cout << v;
    }
}


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        vec[i].resize(n);
        path[i].resize(n);
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                vec[i][j] = 99;
                path[i][j] = i
            }


    vec[0][2] = 8;
    vec[2][1] = 13;
    vec[1][3] = 4;
    vec[3][4] = 3;
    vec[3][7] = 3;
    vec[6][7] = 2;
    vec[5][6] = 5;
    vec[5][2] = 9;
    vec[2][4] = 7;
    vec[4][6] = 4;



    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if(vec[i][k] + vec[k][j] < vec[i][j])
                {
                    vec[i][j] = vec[i][k] + vec[k][j];
                    path[i][j] = k;
                }


    Path(0, 7);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых добавьте инициализацию массивов (по умолчанию 0, и даже расстояние не ищет).

```
for (int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
    for (int j=0;j<vec[i].size();j++){
       vec[i][j] = 99;
       path[i][j] = i;
}
```

После чего подумайте что именно храниться в массиве path.

```
void Path(int u, int v)
{ 
   if (vec[u][v] == 99){
      cout << "No path found"; 
      return;   
   }
   do {
      cout << v<<" ";
      v = path[u][v];
   } while (u != v);
   cout << u<<endl;
}
```

Выводит путь с конца. Один из вариантов, но реализация не совсем стандартная.

P.S. а как у вас скомпилировало объявление `vector<vector<int> > vec(n);` без пробела между двух знаков `>`?

Comment: случайно не скопировал инициализацию, она была. По идее должно выводить именно с конца, но выводит не верно. в path[a][b] должна находится вершина в которую необходимо пойти что бы попасть в б по кротчайшему пути, например если путь имеет ввид a c d b, то path[a][b] = c, path[c][b] = d и так далее. в последних компиляторах не обязательно ставить пробелы.

Comment: Начиная с C++11 несколько правых угловых скобок в параметрах шаблона (если они вложены) интерпретируются как закрытие списков аргументов шаблонов [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#.D0.A3.D0.B3.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BA.D0.B8)